# sql injection "Slep"

Tags: mysql, php, sql

how to determine ip address or url address logs ?
i have this in my mysql-slow-query

```
    /usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
# Time: 200419 11:12:39
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 51.904912  Lock_time: 0.000103 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
use lastfiles;
SET timestamp=1587287559;
SELECT id,name,descr,filename,size,category,seeders,leechers,added FROM torrents WHERE category IN (25 AnD SlEeP(3000)) AND visible='yes' ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 15;
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
# Time: 200419 11:43:06
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 973.189006  Lock_time: 0.000097 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
use lastfiles;
SET timestamp=1587289386;
SELECT id,name,descr,filename,size,category,seeders,leechers,added FROM torrents WHERE category IN (25 AnD SlEeP(3000)) AND visible='yes' ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 15;
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
# Time: 200419 11:59:27
# User@Host: root[root] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 144.803710  Lock_time: 0.000022 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
use lastfiles;
SET timestamp=1587290367;
SELECT id,name,descr,filename,size,category,seeders,leechers,added FROM torrents WHERE category IN (25 AnD SlEeP(3000)) AND visible='yes' ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 15;
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
# Time: 200419 12:21:58
# User@Host: nutecredinstare[nutecredinstare] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 590.385342  Lock_time: 0.000102 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
use lastfiles;
SET timestamp=1587291718;
SELECT id,name,descr,filename,size,category,seeders,leechers,added FROM torrents WHERE category IN (25 AnD SlEeP(3000)) AND visible='yes' ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 15;
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
# Time: 200419 12:27:31
# User@Host: nutecredinstare[nutecredinstare] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 18.139393  Lock_time: 0.000039 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
use lastfiles;
SET timestamp=1587292051;
SELECT id,name,descr,filename,size,category,seeders,leechers,added FROM torrents WHERE category IN (25 AnD SlEeP(3000)) AND visible='yes' ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 15;
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
# Time: 200419 12:51:08
# User@Host: nutecredinstare[nutecredinstare] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 530.583547  Lock_time: 0.000022 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
use lastfiles;
SET timestamp=1587293468;
SELECT id,name,descr,filename,size,category,seeders,leechers,added FROM torrents WHERE category IN (25 AnD SlEeP(3000)) AND visible='yes' ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 15;
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
# Time: 200419 12:58:07
# User@Host: nutecredinstare[nutecredinstare] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 43.678108  Lock_time: 0.000078 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
use lastfiles;
SET timestamp=1587293887;
SELECT id,name,descr,filename,size,category,seeders,leechers,added FROM torrents WHERE category IN (25 AnD SlEeP(3000)) AND visible='yes' ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 15;
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
# Time: 200419 13:13:41
# User@Host: nutecredinstare[nutecredinstare] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 72.950484  Lock_time: 0.000083 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
use lastfiles;
SET timestamp=1587294821;
SELECT id,name,descr,filename,size,category,seeders,leechers,added FROM torrents WHERE category IN (25 AnD SlEeP(3000)) AND visible='yes' ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 15;
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
# Time: 200419 13:26:14
# User@Host: nutecredinstare[nutecredinstare] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 45.907777  Lock_time: 0.000025 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
use lastfiles;
SET timestamp=1587295574;
SELECT id,name,descr,filename,size,category,seeders,leechers,added FROM torrents WHERE category IN (25 AnD SlEeP(3000)) AND visible='yes' ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 15;
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
# Time: 200419 13:48:59
# User@Host: nutecredinstare[nutecredinstare] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 1106.049268  Lock_time: 0.000077 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
use lastfiles;
SET timestamp=1587296939;
SELECT id,name,descr,filename,size,category,seeders,leechers,added FROM torrents WHERE category IN (25 AnD SlEeP(3000)) AND visible='yes' ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 15;
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
# Time: 200419 13:56:32
# User@Host: nutecredinstare[nutecredinstare] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 338.521235  Lock_time: 0.000076 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
use lastfiles;
SET timestamp=1587297392;
SELECT id,name,descr,filename,size,category,seeders,leechers,added FROM torrents WHERE category IN (25 AnD SlEeP(3000)) AND visible='yes' ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 15;
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
# Time: 200419 14:06:26
# User@Host: nutecredinstare[nutecredinstare] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 321.585240  Lock_time: 0.000103 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
use lastfiles;
SET timestamp=1587297986;
SELECT id,name,descr,filename,size,category,seeders,leechers,added FROM torrents WHERE category IN (25 AnD SlEeP(3000)) AND visible='yes' ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 15;
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
# Time: 200419 14:12:51
# User@Host: nutecredinstare[nutecredinstare] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 83.491684  Lock_time: 0.000038 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
use lastfiles;
SET timestamp=1587298371;
SELECT id,name,descr,filename,size,category,seeders,leechers,added FROM torrents WHERE category IN (25 AnD SlEeP(3000)) AND visible='yes' ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT 15;
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.5.62-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log ((Ubuntu)). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
```

Comment: i can't find in which file.php the injection is found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find your `<form>`.

Find where you "interpolate" to build a list of ids.

The Hacker is being nice to you -- he is showing your vulnerability is a relatively harmless way.

He is probably constructing a URL that is providing an "id" from the form, but having it say

```
... &id=25+AnD+SlEeP(3000) ...
```

Then you are doing

```
$query = "SELECT ... " + $_GET['id'] + ...
```

instead of escaping or binding.

Comment: $category = (int)$_GET['cat']; this is safe?

Comment: @GhitaDan - That might work for INT, but not for any kind place where you need a string.  The hacker will close the quote that you have, then do nasties.